# PowerShell To Set Folder Permissions

Tags: file-permissions, powershell-3.0

I am trying to use the "default" options in applying folder permissions; by that, I mean that using the "Full Controll, Write, Read, etc" in the 'Properties' for a folder.

The following script works to add the user in, but it applies "Special Permissions" - not the ones with the tick boxes for the ones visible in the properties menu of the folder:

```powershell
$Acl = Get-Acl "\\R9N2WRN\Share"

$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ("user","FullControl","Allow")

$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl "\\R9N2WRN\Share" $Acl
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Specifying inheritance in the [`FileSystemAccessRule()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule) constructor fixes this, as demonstrated by the modified code below (notice the two new constuctor parameters inserted between `"FullControl"` and `"Allow"`).

```powershell
$Acl = Get-Acl "\\R9N2WRN\Share"

$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("user", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")

$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl "\\R9N2WRN\Share" $Acl
```

According to [this topic](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/8d02271f-366e-40aa-a14b-6f25591b3e25/permissions-from-setacl-only-show-up-in-advanced-settings)

> "when you create a FileSystemAccessRule the way you have, the
> InheritanceFlags property is set to None.  In the GUI, this
> corresponds to an ACE with the Apply To box set to "This Folder Only",
> and that type of entry has to be viewed through the Advanced
> settings."

I have tested the modification and it works, but of course credit is due to the MVP posting the answer in that topic.

Answer (score 10):

Referring to [Gamaliel 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49188364/1501497): `$args` is a [powershell automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3) which contains an array of values for undeclared parameters that are passed to a script, scriptblock or function at runtime - as such cannot be used the way Gamaliel is using it.
This is actually working:

```powershell
$myPath = 'C:\whatever.file'
# get actual Acl entry
$myAcl = Get-Acl "$myPath"
$myAclEntry = "Domain\User","FullControl","Allow"
$myAccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($myAclEntry)
# prepare new Acl
$myAcl.SetAccessRule($myAccessRule)
$myAcl | Set-Acl "$MyPath"
# check if added entry present
Get-Acl "$myPath" | fl
```

Answer (score 7):

Another example using PowerShell for set permissions (File / Directory) :

## Verify permissions

```powershell
Get-Acl "C:\file.txt" | fl *
```

## Apply full permissions for everyone

```powershell
$acl = Get-Acl "C:\file.txt"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("everyone","FullControl","Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl "C:\file.txt"
```

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: This does not appear to work - it ended up with "special permissions" set for the user, not full control.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I just want to share another example whos could be adaptative to set permissions that can be usefull and it works for me.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder why it didn't work for me - maybe I did it wrong!

Comment: the accessRule line returns: constructor not found

Comment: Sorry all, I'm just trying to remedy my mistake.

Comment: Here is a set of arguments: https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/04/18/how-to-manage-file-system-acls-with-powershell-scripts/

Answer (score 6):

In case you need to deal with a lot of folders containing subfolders and other recursive stuff. Small improvement on [@Mike L'Angelo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52945266/1501497):

```powershell
$mypath = "path_to_folder"
$myacl = Get-Acl $mypath
$myaclentry = "username","FullControl","Allow"
$myaccessrule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($myaclentry)
$myacl.SetAccessRule($myaccessrule)
Get-ChildItem -Path "$mypath" -Recurse -Force | Set-Acl -AclObject $myacl -Verbose
```

Verbosity is optional in the last line

Answer (score 2):

This One work for me

```
$path = "C:\test"
$name = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$acl = Get-Acl "C:\test"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($name,"FullControl","Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl "C:\test"
Get-ChildItem -Path "$path" -Recurse -Force | Set-Acl -aclObject $acl -Verbose
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me where the others didn't. It's really in the `$accessRule` setting. I also appreciate that this one keeps access for the logged in user since I'd prefer to restrict that way.

Answer (score -2):

```powershell
$path = "C:\DemoFolder"
$acl = Get-Acl $path
$username = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$Attribs = $username, "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AcessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Attribs)
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl $path
Get-ChildItem -Path "$path" -Recourse -Force | Set-Acl -aclObject $acl -Verbose
```

Comment: Downvoting just because there's a typo here and the edit queue is full. The last line should be `Get-ChildItem -Path "$path" -Recurse -Force | Set-Acl -aclObject $acl -Verbose`