# I am unable to uninstall cygwin on windows 10

Tags: terminal, cygwin

I have downloaded cygwin for windows 10 for a course but it doesnt work with the command prompts so I want to uninstall. I cant uninstall from the config panel as it is not in the list and unable to delete the file directly as it says I havent got the right admin permission although I am logged on as admin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47359190/cant-delete-cygwin-completely-in-windows-10

Comment: Deleting the directory where Cygwin is installed should work. If not, please show our you are trying to delete it.