# Prevent moving/deleting folders but not subfolders or files

Tags: powershell, ntfs

I'm searching for a script that could accomplish the following:

We want to prevent users from moving/deleting or editing folders in de root. 
for example:

- Root (Prevent from deleting and moving folders or files)

  - Folder1 (Folder itself could not be editen, everything underneath should be 
    possible)

I want this to be an script, because its about 600GB. I could do in manually, but that takes a lot of time.

I can work with Powershell, but coudnt find anything to accomplish this.

Hope you can help me out!

Comment: SO is not a place to ask for scripts. You should have a look at [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). If you're only looking for scripts you could try to find something fitting in the [Powershell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell To Set Folder Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779423/powershell-to-set-folder-permissions)