# Set Windows file system security settings programatically. (GUI equivalent)

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, security, filesystems

I want to set the security settings of a Drive and the children folders for a specific user programatically. (PowerShell or C#)
How can i 'Add' and 'Remove' permission entries with the "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permissions entries from this object" option.
[image]

Comment: For PowerShell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779423/powershell-to-set-folder-permissions